# Try-Catch Formatting C#

Tags: c#, try-catch

I'm trying to make a fully functioning calculator application for a school assignment. To do that though I need to use try-catch to handle the DivideByZero error this is my code right now:

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type 1st number: ");
    num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("type 2nd number: ");
    num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("type operation( x , / , +, -, Fs) ");
    operation = Console.ReadLine();
}

catch(DivideByZeroException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry moron you can't divide by zero");
}
```

but it's not working. It seems to make my code at the top invalid. Does anybody know how to format it properly?

P.S. Full code here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Calculator_MK._2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculator();

        }

        private static void Calculator()
        {
            decimal num1;
            decimal num2;
            string operation;
            decimal result;
            decimal num3;
            decimal num4;

            Console.WriteLine("This is IK's Calculator program that should work if you do everything I say");
            Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type 1st number: ");
                num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                Console.Write("type 2nd number: ");
                num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("type operation( x , / , +, -, Fs) ");
                operation = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            catch(DivideByZeroException)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Sorry moron you can't divide by zero");

            }

            if (operation == "x")
            {
                result = num1 * num2;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2}", num1, num2, result);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            else if (operation == "/")
            {
                result = num1 / num2;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2}", num1, num2, result);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }


            else if (operation == "+")
            {
                result = num1 + num2;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", num1, num2, result);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (operation == "-")
            {
                result = num1 - num2;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = {2}", num1, num2, result);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (operation == "Fs")
            {

                int a = 0;
                int b = 1;
                int c = 1;

                Console.WriteLine(a); 
                Console.WriteLine(b); 

                for (; c <= 34; c = a + b)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(c); 
                    a = b;
                    b = c;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            }
            if (num2 == 0)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Can't divide by zero fool");



            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `catch(DivideByZeroException Ex)`

Comment: You need to put operation logic inside `try` block.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Any error?

Comment: @Gusman: That was my thought too, but it's not the case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The `try` block has to be around the code that causes the exception, in your case this is

```
result = num1 / num2;
```

But it would be better to check there for `0` before you call this line and therefore avoid the exception.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that you have declared the try/catch in the wrong place in the application:

```
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type 1st number: ");
            num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.Write("type 2nd number: ");
            num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("type operation( x , / , +, -, Fs) ");
            operation = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        catch(DivideByZeroException)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Sorry moron you can't divide by zero");

        }
```

All that is going on here are string to number conversions. There are no mathematical operations that could result in `DivideByZeroException` exceptions.

Instead, you could wrap the divide operation and anything after it you don't want to run if there is an exception:

```
        else if (operation == "/")
        {
            try
            {
                result = num1 / num2;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2}", num1, num2, result);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry moron you can't divide by zero");
            }
        }
```

That said, it is not a good practice to allow exceptions to happen in C# if they can be avoided. In this case, you only need to check the divisor to ensure it is not zero to avoid an exception from occurring.

```
        else if (operation == "/")
        {
            if (num2 != 0)
            {
                result = num1 / num2;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2}", num1, num2, result);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry moron you can't divide by zero");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to `try` the operation itself and not the selection of the operation:

```
else if (operation == "/")
{
   try
   {
                result = num1 / num2;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2}", num1, num2, result);
                Console.ReadLine();
   }
   catch(DivideByZeroException ex)
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry moron you can't divide by zero");

   }

}
```

Right now you try to read inputs from the User. If the user inputs something wrong whichc would throw an exception, your `try` block would trigger but the `catch` wont, because you are looking for a `DivideByZeroException`, which wont occur by input